# how to convert different datatypes to int in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a `nvarchar(200)` column in a table that contains a mix of integers (as strings) and non-integer strings and symbols also. E.g. Some sample data :-

Excuse me for my typing in my initial post I mentioned varchar(200) but in fact it is 'nvarchar(200)'

```
02
0
.../
125
00125
/2009
1000
0002589
000.00125
```

Marathi numbers [like](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://forum.brillkids.com/gallery/5585/Thumbnail.jpg&imgrefurl=http://forum.brillkids.com/downloads/?sa=view;id=5585&h=320&w=425&sz=5&tbnid=-h6RTrMy3PIFkM%3a&tbnh=96&tbnw=127&zoom=1&usg=__nRz1UTjPwAaTH31m8V3EnUOv7s4=&docid=W6yjFJQEv9zSYM&sa=X&ei=CRUCUavPHsaH0AXLmYHgDg&ved=0CEoQ9QEwBA&dur=287) & [letters](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://sanskritdocuments.org/marathi/eshala/allwrite001.jpg&imgrefurl=http://sanskritdocuments.org/marathi/eshala/&h=3051&w=2111&sz=566&tbnid=DdqEBTN1C2qwwM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=62&zoom=1&usg=__zRJQ6g8uCYPeaGcE0dIDKlOiPjM=&docid=FSHXRzbvO7XOPM&sa=X&ei=llQCUZWvAYqU0QXjwoGgAg&ved=0CD0Q9QEwAQ&dur=392)

how can I order this Column?

Comment: Can you show a proper sample and expected output after ordering.. ?

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MYSQL?

Comment: In case your column has some `Marathi Nos`, I doubt whether we can use `Order By`. But if it's possible than can you please give us the sample `table` and `Marathi nos`too? Because I doubt about how can you stored `Marathi Nos` in your Table.

Comment: I think this question is `MISLEADING`, as i Doubt whether one can really insert `MARATHI NOS` in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: @luv: You can insert marathi language in SQL server  by something like `Collation Settings` reFer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(SQL.90).aspx  ( But it will not be supported in a future SQL Server release)

Answer (score 0):

Many DBMS have `CAST()` functions where you can convert one datatype to another.

For MySQL have a look at [this site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to convert a `varchar` to an `INT` given that varchar is holding a proper number.

`SELECT CAST(varCharCol as Int)`

E.g.

`col1 as Varchar(10)`

`col1 = '100'` converting to INT will be successufl

but if `col1 = '100 xyz'` will be unsucessful in the process.

Looking at your string you may have to use number of `LTRIM`, `REPLACE` to get hold of the digits or using a regex to get comma separated numbers. That too it's not very clear how your original string looks like.

- [References](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/can-i-convert-this-string-to-an-integer--94069).

Comment: OP clearly mention in his question that `it contain mix of integers (as strings) and non-integer strings and symbols`

Comment: @satindersingh so what you are you trying to say? ;) I have mentioned that `CAST` can only be used for a proper number within a `varchar()`... OP needs to literally clean up his column values if he wants to order by the `number`.

Comment: @narendra Are you alright if the column is sorted/orderd by `alpahnumerics` without special characters?

Comment: what i am trying to say is, OP already cleared in his question **mix Values**  so as far i knw `Cast` is not applicalble here

Comment: *Looking at your string you may have to use number of LTRIM, REPLACE to get hold of the digits or using a regex to get comma separated numbers. That too it's not very clear how your original string looks like.*.. in my answer to the end..

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **CAST and Convert** to convert string type value to int type. but be sure the value should numeric.

```
select convert(int,'123')

select CAST('123' as int)
```

Comment: I don't think whether it will work, as in the question it is stated that field column contains mixed of **`Integers and Non-Integer`**

Comment: @Madhu: OP clearly mentioned  `it contain mix of integers (as strings) and non-integer strings and symbols`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

`SELECT CASE` 
`WHEN ISNUMERIC(colName)=1 THEN ROUND(colName, 0)
 ELSE 0 END AS [colName]` 
`FROM tblName`

Comment: was just thinking of an approach like this. :)